# jQuery mouse events on disabled form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Which jQuery mouse events are actually fired on a disabled form field like a disabled checkbox ?

Comment: Any reason you ask, or just out of sheer curiosity?

Comment: I need some mouse event to fire some code on a dsiabled checkbox...

Comment: So you're out of luck.. disabled element means, among other things, disable any events for this element.

Comment: Also note, that since the mouse events are not called, they do not propagate down the DOM nodes either.  So you can not put the check box inside the span and try to catch events on the span.  My suggestion for you is to not use the disabled attribute and maintain the disable state with `$.data`. With other events and stuff you could program in the disabled features including not toggling selection and all the styling...hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of jQuery mouse events not working with disabled input.
But you can make overlay element located above input and bind events to him [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zcHc4/7/)

Comment: He asked what events are working, not what events are not working.

Comment: There are no other events in jQuery for mouse so i can say that none of them

Comment: It's not clear in the answer. Anyway, good thing that you jsFiddled it. :)

Comment: One interesting thing which I found was on iPad, "touchstart" event is fired on a disabled input field..Any ideas why ?

Comment: `touchstart` is global event binded to viewport

Comment: @ant_Ti : When you say global event binded to viewport , which are some of the other events and what difference does that make?

Comment: touch events works like delegate, they binded to viewport and always trigger on touch no matter enabled or disabled element that doesn't happens with mouse events

Answer (score 1):

Probably none of them. That's meaning of "Disabled"

```
<input disabled="disabled" />
<script>

$("input").click(function(){
     alert("Clicked");
});
</script>
```

[alert is not thrown](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/f851a/1)

Comment: One interesting thing which I found was on iPad, "touchstart" event is fired on a disabled input field..Any ideas why ?

Comment: @test because they have different "rules" than others.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on ant_Ti, while this is true that no events work. You can wrap it in a container: http://jsfiddle.net/zcHc4/4/